# Filtro em array dentro de objeto Angular

Tags: angularjs

1 Tenho um array de objetos de viagens
2 cada viagem tem um array de usuarios (viajantes)
preciso criar um filtro para listar os viajantes
criei um filtro para os destinos, mas para os usuarios nao da certo.
alguem tem alguma dica?

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module("viagem", []);

  app.controller("viagemController", function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.viagens = [  
                     {  
                        "id":1,
                        "nomeTipoViagem":"Manutenção",
                        "destino":"Maranhâo",
                        "data":"2015-07-02",
                        "clientes":[  
                           {  
                              "nickname":"Cereais Comebem"
                           }
                        ],
                        "viajantes":[  
                           {  
                              "id_usuario":1,
                              "nome":"José Amaral"
                           },
                           {  
                              "id_usuario":2,
                              "nome":"Fernando Oliveira"
                           }
                        ],
                        "observacoes":null
                     }
                  ];
  });

</script>
```

```
  <body ng-app="viagem">
    {{viagens}}
    <table  ng-controller="viagemController" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Destino</th>
          <th>Viajantes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="filtroDestino" ng-init="filtroDestino=''" />
          </td>

          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="filtroViajante" ng-init="filtroViajante=''" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="viagem in viagens  | filter:{destino:filtroDestino} | filter:{tipo:filtroTipo}">
          <td>{{viagem.destino}}</td>
          <td>
            <span ng-repeat="usuario in viagem.viajantes">{{usuario.nome}}                                                         <br />
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

[Plunker - Código](http://plnkr.co/edit/woURHelLgb5HxspfzdIE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce so precisa fazer uma mudanca simples no seu codigo:

```
<td>
  <span ng-repeat="usuario in viagem.viajantes | filter:{nome:filtroViajante}">
      {{usuario.nome}} <br />
  </span>
</td>
```

[Plunker - Codigo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AU3YmNPYZpAuRvEuG6HV?p=preview)